# http.client - ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: django

```
def checkUrl(url):
    p = urlparse(url)
    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(p.netloc)
    conn.request('HEAD', p.path)
    resp = conn.getresponse()
    return resp.status < 400

all_urls = URL.objects.all()

for u in all_urls:
    my_url = u.url
    result = checkUrl(my_url)
    print(result)
```

There are 3090 urls in model "URL". It works but after object 2895, the error occurs:
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

'connection closed by remote host' may caused by many reasons, here is a possible scene:
The remote host configured max-open connections per ip, and you exceed the limit because you didn't close connection timly.

To find out a more precise answer, informations like network packet captured by wireshark or tcpdump are needed.

Answer (score -2):

from urllib.parse import urlparse
import http.client

Comment: You may need to add these modules

Comment: from urllib.parse import urlparse
import http.client

def checkUrl(url):
    p = urlparse(url)
    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(p.netloc)
    conn.request('HEAD', p.path)
    resp = conn.getresponse()
    return resp.status < 400

all_urls = URL.objects.all()

for u in all_urls:
    my_url = u.url
    result = checkUrl(my_url)
    print(result)

Comment: Please read [answer] and use the help center to find out about formatting in StackOverflow.

Comment: If the OP was missing the imports they would not have been able to process the first 3000 urls.